# How to remove identical columns in a csv file using Bash

Tags: regex, awk

There are already a lot of questions like this but neither of them did help me. I want to keep this simple:

I have a file (more than 90 columns) like:

```
Class,Gene,col3,Class,Gene,col6,Class
A,FF,23,A,FF,16,A
B,GG,45,B,GG,808,B
C,BB,43,C,BB,76,C
```

I want to keep unique columns so the desired output should be:

```
Class,Gene,col3,col6
A,FF,23,16
B,GG,45,808
C,BB,43,76
```

I used `awk '!a[$0]++'` but it did not remove the repeated columns of the file.

As a side note: I have repetitive columns because I used  `paste`  command to join different files  `column-wise`.

Comment: Do you know which fields are repeated, or do you have to determine it dynamically?

Comment: The command you tried is for removing repeated *rows*, not columns.

Comment: Yes, I do. Their headers are identical also rows of them are identical.

Comment: @Barmar Any help?

Comment: Do you really want to remove all repeated columns, or just the `Class` and `Gene` columns? Should a line like `A,FF,1,A,FF,1` be turned into `A,FF,1` or `A,FF,1,1`?

Comment: I want to keep unique column names. So basically one ```Class``` and  one ```Gene``` should be there and the rest should be numbers related to those genes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk` to print unique columns based on their names in first header row:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","                        # set input/output field separators as comma
}
NR == 1 {                            # for first header row
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)             # loop through all columns
      if (!ucol[$i]++)               # if col name is not in a unique array
         hdr[i]                      # then store column no. in an array hdr
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)             # loop through all columns
      if (i in hdr)                  # if col no. is found in array hdr then print
        printf "%s",(i==1?"":OFS) $i # then print col with OFS
      print ""                       # print line break
}' file
```

```
Class,Gene,col3,col6
A,FF,23,16
B,GG,45,808
C,BB,43,76
```

Comment: Great this worked, many thanks. However, it would be great if you could describe your code a bit then I can get a sense of it :)

Comment: May I ask, `hdr[i]` is short for `hdr[i]=i`?

Comment: @anubhava Thank you so much  

Comment: @MichalH: No `hdr[i]` just stores key `i` without any value.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific case where you're just trying to remove 2 cols added by paste per original file all you need is:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { r=$1 OFS $2; for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=3) r=r OFS $i; print r }
' file
Class,Gene,col3,col6
A,FF,23,16
B,GG,45,808
C,BB,43,76
```

but in other situations where it's not as simple: create an array (`f[]` below) that maps output field numbers (determined based on uniqueness of first line field/column names) to the input field numbers then loop through just the output field numbers (note: you don't have to loop through all of the input fields, just the ones that you're going to output) printing the value of the corresponding input field number:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( !seen[$i]++ ) {
            f[++nf] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Class,Gene,col3,col6
A,FF,23,16
B,GG,45,808
C,BB,43,76
```

Here's a version with more meaningful variable names and a couple of intermediate variables to clarify what's going on:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    numInFlds = NF
    for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=numInFlds; inFldNr++) {
        fldName = $inFldNr
        if ( !seen[fldName]++ ) {
            out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
        }
    }
}
{
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
        fldValue = $inFldNr
        printf "%s%s", fldValue, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Print the first two columns and then iterate in strides of 3 to skip the `Class` and `Gene` columns in the rest of the row.

```
awk -F, '{printf("%s,%s", $1, $2); for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=3) printf(",%s", $i); printf("\n")}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not give col3, col6, ... headers in the output file.

Comment: Needed to use `%s` instead of `%d` so it won't convert strings to `0`.